# Must basis for column space be consist columns?

Tags: matrices

Lets say we have the following Matrix
$$\left[
\begin{matrix}
2 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 2 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{matrix}
\right]$$

Obviously a basis for this would be 
$$\begin{Bmatrix}
\left[
\begin{matrix}
2\\
0\\
0\\
\end{matrix}
\right]
,\left[
\begin{matrix}
0\\
2\\
0\\
\end{matrix}
\right]
\end{Bmatrix}$$
But would another valid basis be
$$\begin{Bmatrix}
\left[
\begin{matrix}
1\\
0\\
0\\
\end{matrix}
\right]
,\left[
\begin{matrix}
0\\
1\\
0\\
\end{matrix}
\right]
\end{Bmatrix}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to the question in the *body* of your post—is
$$
\left\{\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}\right\}
$$
a basis of the column space?—is yes! Remember the the column space of a matrix is *spanned* by the columns, and any spanning set contains a subset which is a basis.  But of course there can be other bases for a subspace.  The second set of vectors is linearly independent and has the same span as the first set, so is also a basis.

The answer to the question in the *title* of your post—must a basis for the column space consist of columns?—is no. That is the point of Abel's answer.

Answer (score 0):

the answer is no to the question that should every basis of the column space of a matrix must have its columns in it. for example another basis for the column space is 
$\pmatrix{1 \\1\\0}, \pmatrix{1\\-1\\0}$. you can take any $ 2 \times 2 $ nonsingular matrix $P$ any basis $\{u_1,u_2\}$ then 
$\{Pu_1, Pu_2\}$ is another basis for the column space of $A.$

Comment: It seems like the OP's question is whether the second set of vectors is a basis.  that doesn't rule out any number of other bases.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang, the title of op's is should the basis consist of columns of a matrix. the answer is no. that is what i tried to illustrate.

Comment: Oh, good point! The question in the title and the question in the body are different.